# Visual Studio 2012 Web Deploy Package does not include the sql script file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a web deploy package for an MVC 4 site using this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323.aspx). Every thing is fine, but I am unable to locate the *.sql file inside the web deploy package.

Comment: Is the *.sql file in a solution folder or in a project?  Also, is its build action set to copy to output folder?

Comment: @TylerOhlsen, I am using this to auto include the script http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576376.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no .sql file. In VS2012 the web publish now supports incremental database schema publish. This is achieved by creating a model of your database. This model is a .dacpac file. When you create a publish profile with the package option the .dacpac is created and placed in the root of the package. If you open the .zip file you will see a file with a name lie dbDacFx***.dacpac that is your database model.